# asp.net - searching for a data containing an apostrophe in the database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Good day! I am having a hard time fixing this problem. I've been searching the answer for this but seemed to be very very hard to look for the most fitting answer.

i use this query to search for a tenant's name based on what the user inputs in the txtSearchRP textbox, it works very well to data with no apostrophe in it, however when the user searches for a name containing ' , it does not function well.

example: user inputs MAX'S to search MAX'S RESTAURANT

SELECT * from tenant WHERE (name LIKE '%" + txtSearchRP.Text +  "%')

Thanks for your help in advance!

---

edit for more information:

I am actually passing the query to sqlDataSource to bind the gridview automatically after the user click THE BUTTON.

SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = SELECT * from tenant WHERE (name LIKE '%" + txtSearchRP.Text +  "%')

Comment: Simply replace single quote in _MAX'S_ with two single quotes i.e. _name LIKE '%MAX''S%'_

Comment: thanks for replying, please note that the like operator must be based on the searchbox(user input) - txtSearcRP.Text. how can i modify (name LIKE '%" + txtSearchRP.Text + "%') using your proposed answer?

Comment: use String's Replace method

Comment: Use NMK's solution because it is SQL Injection free

Comment: with the use of injection method, are there still other possibilities to solve it?

Comment: how to do the String's replace method?

Comment: No offense, learn basics of the language yourself

Comment: no problem, i know the string replace method, what I mean is how to implement the method in my problem. THANKS though for the general answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all who shared their knowledge and effort, finally got the answer through the String replace method

**HERE'S THE 3-LINED CODE**

```
string value = txtSearchRP.Text;
value = value.Replace("'", "['']");
sqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "SELECT * from tenant WHERE  (name LIKE '%" + value.ToString() +"%')";
```

through the joined effort, answers you posted here, we solve the problem in the simplest form :)

Comment: You should be using parameterized statements like NMK shows, and read up on what people mean when they say [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
conn =  new 
    SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT * from tenant WHERE (name LIKE @tenant)", conn);
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@tenant";
param.Value         = "%" + txtSearchRP.Text + "%"; // you can use any wildcard operator 
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: That will be a sql syntax error.  `%@tenant%` is not legal syntax.

Comment: Then Probably you can append the wildcard operator as part of the value.

Comment: are there other way to solve the problem with the use of injection?  thanks though for this, will be trying your answer and update you for the result.

Answer (score 0):

Better way create storedprocedure

**SP :**

```
Create proc sp_Search( @txtSearch nvarchar(150)) 
as begin
  SELECT * from tenant WHERE name like @txtSearch+'%'
end
```

**Code behind :**

```
 string txtSearch = txtSearchRP.Text;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cn.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmdd.CommandText = "sp_Search";
                cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtSearch", txtSearch);
                cmdd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                dr = cmdd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var name = dr["name"].ToString();
                        var location = dr["location"].ToString();
                    }
                } dr.Close();
                conn.Close();

            }
        }
```

**Updated:**
Write a function which returns datatable so that we can bind it to our gridview control as i did in code below

```
 public DataTable bindGridView() 
    {
     string txtSearch = txtSearchRP.Text;
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand();
            cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdd.CommandText = "sp_Search";
             cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtSearch", txtSearch);
            cmdd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dap.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            con.Close();

        }
        return dt;
    }
```

**On Button click :** Call bindGridView() function for binding Gridview control

```
GridView1.DataSource = bindGridView();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks for this, sorry for this question, but how can i pass that to sqldatasource to fill the gridview after i click the button find?

Comment: I include these lines: SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "SELECT * from tenant WHERE  (name LIKE '%" + name +"%'); ModalPopupExtenderRP.Show();  inside the if - while statement to test the name variable, still it's not reading or giving a filtered result when i include an apostrophe in keyword search, but it fucntions well with plain string keyword.

Comment: thank you so much for this example been trying this but i cant just execute what I want to do, thanks though for the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already given, in some applications, you might need to consider [escaping wildcards such as %](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) in the input string provided by the user.

For example, if the user enters "25%", then matching on "%25%%" will return values that contain "25", rather than restricting to values that contain "25%".

You can escape wildcards as follows (for SQL Server):

```
 string value = ... value entered by user;
 value = value.Replace("[", "[[]");
 value = value.Replace("_", "[_]");
 value = value.Replace("%", "[%]");
```